# Room - insert or replace, but keep a database field?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I have in my local database a table called event with the fields:

- id (PK)
- name (text)
- date (time)
- favorite (int, 0 or 1)

The server would give me a list of events, without the favorite field, the favorite field is only local.

I'm using this code to insert events

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertEvents(List<Event> events);
```

The thing is that, if an event is already stored in the local database, it will loose the favorite property, and it will always be false after is inserted and replaced.

Is there a way to bulk insert like this, but keep the favorite field?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with this bulk insert

Comment: can u share the code for insertEvents(List<Event> events) method

Comment: @UdayRamjiyani is just that , is an abstract method for Dao https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Dao.html

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you find a solution to it?

Comment: @jlively no, there is currently no solution for this. :(

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same situation. This is how I solved it.
Since the data coming from the server is immutable and would reset local values, I decided to keep a table for the data coming from the server and another for the "local" data.

Table `ServerData` for remote data.

Table `ServerDataAttrs` for local only data.

`ServerDataAttrs` contains all local columns along with the primary key `id` from table `ServerData`.

```
ServerData.id == ServerDataAttrs.id
```

This way, each row from `ServerDataAttrs` is related to its correspondent row in `ServerData` (the other way around is not required, that is why I use later `LEFT JOIN`). You can always replace data on `ServerData` and local data from `ServerDataAttrs` will remain untouched.

I did not set a foreign key to avoid accidental removal. I deleted the local data only when calling delete method from its `DAO`.

For querying the data, you can create a `POJO` that has all remote and local values together.

```
public class ServerDataWithAttrsPojo {
   private long id;
   private String name;
   ...
   private int favorite;

   // public constructor, getters and setters...
}
```

The query must be then a `JOIN` between both tables.

```
SELECT sd.id, sd.name, ...., sda.favorite
FROM ServerData sd LEFT JOIN ServerDataAttrs sda ON sd.id = sda.id
```

I use `LEFT JOIN` just in case an entity from `ServerData` does not have a row in `ServerDataAttrs` as I mentioned before.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem and this is the scenario of how I've solved it.

- Check if there are favorite items in your DB and fetch them.
- Fetch the data from API.
- Insert all of the data into DB.
- Update your DB with the previously fetched items that have been marked as favorite.